# WCF MSMQ Unit testing

Tags: wcf, unit-testing, msmq, msmqbinding

I have created a custom msmq service with WCF, which uses a custom binding as it needs to do some custom logic at the channel layer, where it calls another wcf service. The service is going to be a core pience of functionality for our systems for at the the next few years. i want to do what I can to make sure the service is robust, but, i'm not sure where to start. Ie testing the response, should I create a mock queue object? how do I test the service is calling another service ?

Comment: I'm also interested in how to go about unit testing msmq functions

Answer (score 2):

Best way I have found to unit test msmq services is to actually unit test the service implementation, then do an integration test using msmq with a mock repository. To see if writes are working.