# Unit Testing WCF Service is launching

Tags: c#, wcf, unit-testing

I'm new to WCF.  I've created a basic service and engineer tested it with the debugger and WCFTestClient.  I've never written my own WCF client.  Now I need to build unit tests for the service.

My classes:

```
IXService
CXService
CServiceLauncher
```

(Yes, I know the C prefix does not meet current standards, but it is required by my client's standards.)

My service functionality can be tested directly against `XService`, but I need to test `CServiceLauncher` as well.  All I want to do is connect to a URI and discover if there is a service running there and what methods it offers.

Other questions I read:

- [AddressAccessDeniedException "Your process does not have access rights to this namespace" when Unit testing WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14563557/unit-test-wcf-service) -
  starts service host in unit test
- [WCF Unit Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152338/wcf-unit-test) - recommends
  hosting the service in unit test, makes a vague reference to
  connecting to service via HTTP
- [WCF MSMQ Unit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691066/wcf-msmq-unit-testing) -
  references MSMQ, which is more detailed than I need
- [Unit test WCF method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929882/unit-test-wcf-method) - I never knew I could auto generate tests, but the system isn't smart enough to know what to assert.

Test outline:

```
    public void StartUiTest()
    {
        Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/MyService");
        string soapAddress = "soap";
        IUserInterface target = new CServiceLauncher(baseAddress, soapAddress);
        try
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(true, target.StartUi());
            /// @todo Assert.IsTrue(serviceIsRunning);
            /// @todo Assert.IsTrue(service.ExposedMethods.Count() > 4);
            Assert.Inconclusive("This tells us nothing about the service");
        }
        finally
        {
            target.StopUi();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is integration test and not unit test

Comment: Well, without re-factoring the code to allow injection of the service implementation object into the ServiceLauncher, how would you suggest converting it to a unit test?

Comment: To test `CServiceLauncher` I would mock a service and verify that say a `Start` method was called. If it takes more than 10-15 lines per test, I would stop and rethink how can mock the thing to allow me to write a test in 10-15 lines.

Comment: Even if we inject a mock service into CServiceLauncher, we still are in the position of needing to see if the injected service was launched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed to build a simple client.

Reference:
http://webbeyond.blogspot.com/2012/11/wcf-simple-wcf-client-example.html

1. Add Service Reference to test project
2. Add to test file:

   `using System.ServiceModel;`

   `using MyTests.ServiceReferenceNamespace;`

Code inside try is now:

```
            Assert.AreEqual(true, target.StartUi());
            XServiceClient client = new XServiceClient();
            client.GetSessionID();
            Assert.AreEqual(CommunicationState.Opened, client.State, "Wrong communication state after first call");
```

Comment: FYI, the first State test does not test that the service was started.  If the service was not started I get an exception when I call client.GetSessionID().  `client.Endpoint.Contract.Operations.Count` fulfills my earlier suggestion of getting `service.ExposedMethods.Count()` but also works fine even if the service is not running.  I'll still accept other answers if someone can suggest a better way than exceptions to detect if the service is running.

Comment: client.Open(); opens the connection whether the service is running or not.  No exceptions, no failure when asserting client.State.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a real answer so please take it easy.

I have been trying to do similar things and what I have learnt that integration testing is difficult. It is difficult because there are many hidden tasks that you need to do, such as:

- Make sure you can run the tests regularly
- Make sure integration tests can run on the test environment
- Maintain different config files, as your environment will be different from the test one
- Configure the thing that would automate running of integration tests (CI)
- Pray there will be no changes to the paths, test environment, config, hosting platforms etc
- Fight security permissions, as usually test thing is not able to host WCF services without admin permissions
- Maintain your test harness

To me, this was huge headache and little gain. Don't get me wrong, integration testing is a positive thing, it just requires *a lot* of time to develop and support.

What have I learnt? Is that do not bother with integration testing of WCF services. Instead I write a lot of unit-tests, to test the contract, state and behaviour. By covering those, I can become sure in a quality of software. And I fight integration of WCF during deployment. This is usually a single battle to configure environment or VM and then next time, deployment goes nice and smooth in an (semi-)automated manner.

Most people would also automate deployment with [Chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/) and alike, those tools can fully configure environment and deploy WCF service.